# How to remove popup menus in a perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, perspective, popupmenu

I am working with Eclipse. I am developing a new perspective. I need to remove some Eclipse platform contributions (defined via org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus) in this perspective. Some of these popup menu options to be removed ar "Debug As...", for example.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Eclipse Activities](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/).